# Why does JVM heap keep growing?

Tags: java, heap-memory

I write a simple program and use jconsole.exe to monitor its heap size.

```
public class HeapTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true) {
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result
[image]

I don't understand why the heap size keeps growing. I don't new() any Object in my program.

What is the heap used for in my program?

I don't add any additional arguments to jconsole.exe; just double click on it, then load the java process according to PID.

Environment: Java 1.8.0_25 under windows 7

Comment: it might be doing something in background, I am sure if you click perform GC (which you should not in live environment), it will drop immediately.

Comment: @SMA - It might be due to the background threads running in JVM.. They have their own overhead.. There will be atleast 4 other threads running with `main` thread when JVM starts. The heap might be growing steadily due to their execution.

Comment: Yeah we do have finalizer, main etc threads in background that's what i meant..

Comment: Could somebody reproduce this behaviour? Looks like unreproducable issue. I believe that author has tangled with this measuring

Comment: @Andremoniy - What is your environment? Linux, Windows or Mac?

Comment: @Andremoniy - Ya. The rate at which the heap is growing is indeed suspicious. The JIT will most probably optimize it to only one jump instruction. I don't see why *this* piece of code should affect heap..

Comment: @lyen Win7 64, java 1.8.0.31

Comment: Have you tried checking the bytecode? Might reveal something whats happening and if it is indeed this class.

Comment: @Obicere - That's the first thing that I did. You can get nothing in byte code.. Also, note that things like these are *heavily* dependant in hotspot optimizations.

Comment: Provide us how did you run jconsole? Looks like it gathers info about itself, not about you app

Comment: I can replicate it in OSX. It seems that the growth is in the Eden space and once GC occurs, memory is released and the process starts again. It could be the housekeeping data between two GCs.

Comment: Looks like it is some sort of overhead of attaching JConsole to a running JVM. Can communication between JVM and JConsole allocate some objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no memory leak here. Replicated it in OSX as well. It would be the book keeping data generated by the normal functioning of the VM including that for the GC. The eden goes up and once the GC occurs, the memory used by the heap (eden) is reduced and the cycle starts again.

The confusing aspect is that there are no objects being created explictly by the program but it would make sense to expound that the JVM would be doing so and hence the gradual increase in eden space till the next GC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JConsole alternative command jmap monitor java process, and you can find java heap size is stationary.

Answer (score 0):

you've assumed that main( ) is your only thread, which is an incorrect assumption.  There are other threads that will allocate objects