# Why java heap keeps increasing?

Tags: java, jvm

This is my code:

```
public class Main2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(100000);
    }

}
```

In the above code, just sleep the main thread. But, I can see heap keeps increasing in JVisualVM Visual GC. So, why java heap keeps increasing?

Comment: Why are you monitoring the heap in this example?

Comment: Check this, It might be helpful to understand the behavior  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28689203/why-does-jvm-heap-keep-growing)

Comment: Just a thought ,may be the exception objects thrown from the main method. Did you check the type of objects being garbage collected?

Comment: Running JVisualVM uses memory (lots actually) try reducing the polling rate and you will see the increase reduce proportionally.  Try using `jstat` from the command line every so often instead.